# Convert HTTP links to HTTPS in ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, url, iis, https

I have external free MP3 file (non-coyrighted) URLs on an http web-site.
I want to let users play these mp3 urls from my HTTPS site written in ASP.NET MVC.

How can I convert these HTTP urls to HTTPS urls on (using some sort of proxy on IIS) the fly without affecting performance.

**EDIT:**
The http site hosting mp3 is not mine. It has different domain name from my https site and is hosted on some other server by someone else. Any request for mp3 url on the http site (not owned by me) should appear to come through an https site (either my https site or some other). I do not have control over the http site, otherwise I would have put SSL on that site.

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind https binding with SSL certificate and redirect all the request from HTTP to https.

for redirect, you could use below url rewrite rule in your web.config file.

```
    <system.webServer>    
   <rewrite>    
      <rules>    
      <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">    
   <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false"/>    
   <conditions>    
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>    
   </conditions>    
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>    
      </rule>    
      </rules>    
   </rewrite>    
</system.webServer>
```

For certificate configuration following link can be helpful:  [Enabling SSL on IIS](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates)

Comment: This URL might be helpful to you. It helped me resolved my HTTP to HTTPS redirection issue. https://justinacton.com/2015/11/14/iis-8-redirect-http-to-https-3/

Comment: This can resolve my HTTP to HTTPS. However I want someone else's HTTP be accessible via my HTTPS.                                                                                                 Eg. http://www.bkdrluhar.com/97-Audio%20Songs/5000-1-Hit%20Songs-1/001-Prem%20Se%20Bas%20Do%20Dhadi.mp3                                                            should be accessible through my https site                                                                               https://mysite/001-Prem%20Se%20Bas%20Do%20Dhadi.mp3

Comment: if the  mp3 is on another site you could use iis [reverse proxy](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2016/08/25/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps/) or rewrite rule to rewrite page with the mp3 files in your site. make sure that the other site is not restricted the reverse proxy.